# Reading cr3 images for data processing on python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a number of raw photos in cr3 files and I would like to do some data processing using raw like color calibration using opencv.

My program works fine with jpg files. But is there a way that I can open cr3 on python directly or I can massively convert cr3 to jpg to further process?

I tried to use rawlib to convert a cr3 file to pgm format which can be read in python and to further process in openCV. But it looks rather strange as if a greenish layer is on the image.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```py
  with open(link, 'rb') as ipf:
    format = ipf.readline().decode()
    dim = ipf.readline().decode()
    width, height = dim.split(' ')
    width = int(width)
    height = int(height)
    print(width, height)
    limit = ipf.readline().decode()
    limit = int(limit)
    if limit == 65535:
        rawp = np.frombuffer(ipf.read(), dtype='>u2')
        rawp = rawp.reshape((height, width))
  
  # Extract color channels 
  p0 = rawp[::2, ::2]
  p1 = rawp[::2, 1::2]
  p2 = rawp[1::2, ::2]
  p3 = rawp[1::2, 1::2]
  # cv2_showImg(p0)
  # cv2_showImg(p1)
  # cv2_showImg(p2)
  # cv2_showImg(p3)
  # Combine as an RGB image that opencv can process
  # R is P0 G is P1 B is P3
  comp = [p3, p1, p0]
  comp = [np.reshape(p, (height>>1, width>>1, 1)) for p in comp]
  comp = np.concatenate(comp, axis=2)
  comp = comp.astype('float64')
 
  comp = comp / np.max(comp) *255
  comp = comp.astype('uint8')
  # cv2_showImg(comp)

  return comp
```

Comment: Imagemagick can convert all your CR3 files to JPG or PNG or whatever format you want. It comes native on Linux and can be installed on Mac or Windows. You can also use Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick.

Comment: @fmw42 I don't know what version of ImageMagick you're using, but the version of ImageMagick shipped on most Linux distributions does not support CR3 files. You'll get an error that looks like this if you try to convert a CR3 file to a JPG: `convert-im6.q16: delegate failed`

Comment: `@Raleigh L`Do you have draw or ufraw delegate installed?  If not, you need that delegate. What do you get from `convert -version`? That will tell you what delegates you have.